# Windows Server 2012 R2 - search by file content not working

Tags: windows-search, windows-server-2012-r2

I can't find any .txt, .php, .cs, .html, etc files using the 'search by file content' option in the searchbar in Windows Server 2012 R2.

I can't find the File Service Role.
I can't find the Windows Search service in Services.
I have checked the advanced option "File content".

Comment: You are right!.. is there anyway i can move it? a simple way?

Comment: I am not sure that a user can, but we can ask a mod to help us out.

Answer (score 19):

I decided to provide screenshots, as Windows Server features and roles are now in a single interface and it's not obvious where to look.

#### Step 1. Enable Windows Search Service feature

[image]

#### Step 2. Enable search in contents

[image]

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for your review. I've updated the post text

Comment: In which case why not just [update the answer](https://superuser.com/a/710934/95106) with the images rather than leaving a duplicate answer?

Comment: @Lankymart Does one get points for up-votes on an answer that one only edits rather than posts? I found the screenshots much more helpful than the original answer, which I had already found.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN no, but if that's the end-game with answering, then the StackExchange communities are not for you.

Comment: @Lankymart The purpose of assigning points is to give proper incentives for desired activities. So of course the scoring of answers should be considered in explaining why people choose a particular course of action. Whether that's one's ultimate motive shouldn't matter much otherwise there's little purpose in assigning points in the first place. Even if points aren't this answerer's motive, I think it's important for them to see how much the screenshots mattered. I suppose this should be discussed on meta.superuser.com instead of here. If another reply is warranted, maybe I'll take it there.

Answer (score 7):

In the explorer menu

```
View -> Options -> Change Folder And Search Options
Folder Options -> Search -> Check Always Search File names and Contents ....
```

Comment: Also check that you have the `Windows Search` feature installed (in Server Manager). And then check which locations are indexed in `File Explorer` > `Search` > `Advanced Options` > `Change indexed locations`

Comment: @bounav - Of course, look at `File Explorer` > `Search` > `Advanced Options` because that's the obvious place to find the configuration for windows search.  Not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

findstr /S /L /M /C:"DocumentImportClass" *.*

search file content into folder and sub folders in windows

Answer (score -1):

1+ for Vikash's command.

I would also add that /I to make it case-insensitive

findstr /S /L /M /I /C:"TextToSearch"

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way that worked for me was to select all the files where you suspect the string to be present, then right click and select open with notepad++.
Once all the files are open in different tabs, go to any file tab and do Ctrl+F, type your string and select **Find All in All Opened Documents** and there you go!